# The date function does not work well with a timestamp

Tags: php, date, datetime

I work with php 7.1.4 and when I do an echo of the date () function with the integer 1540193140046 it returns a malformed value (view image). However if I do the same thing using this [tool](https://www.epochconverter.com/) it returns the correct value: 
Monday, 22 October 2018 7:25:40.046

What is the reason?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

PHP timestamps are in seconds, whereas that tool when it sees the big number says:

> Assuming that this timestamp is in milliseconds

try

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1540193140046/1000);
```

and you will get the answer you expect:

```
2018-10-22 09:25:40
```